# NetCDF in julia

Tags: julia, netcdf

After intalling NetCDF in julia,

```
julia> Pkg.status()
1 required packages:
 - NetCDF                        0.3.0
7 additional packages:
 - BinDeps                       0.3.19
 - Compat                        0.7.8
 - Conda                         0.1.8
 - Formatting                    0.1.4
 - JSON                          0.5.0
 - SHA                           0.1.2
 - URIParser                     0.1.1
```

I try simple things like

```
julia> ncinfo("/home/idf/Downloads/air.sig995.2012.nc")
ERROR: UndefVarError: ncinfo not defined

julia>
```

I must be missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia packages are git repositories, one could clone a repository directly or by `Pkg.add()`, it's not equals to loading it, therefore after adding a package and before using it you must load it's contents, and `using` is the right command to do this task,
So:
`using NetCDF;` is the missing statement.